# Router acting as an ad blocker (?)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, google-chrome, router

So I began having troubles with getting Pandora (the music streaming service) and their content wasnt able to load so i began to go through the checks in my cookies, cache, flash, etc. Ended up deleting chrome and all of its system files from my computer.

Re-downloaded chrome and went right to pandora and the problem was still occurring. Checked pandora in Safari and it was the same problem. To add to the frustration, I was just browsing when I got to Forbes website and they wouldn't let me on to the site because they were detecting an ad blocker (???). The real head scratcher- I dont have an ad blocker.

So I tried re-connecting to the internet using my iPhone as a mobile hotspot and I was able to use both Pandora and Forbes (along with other sites that detect ad-blockers). Then when I connect back to my regular home wifi, the problem persists.

And to add to the frustration, my iMac (which is connected via ethernet- not wifi) can play Pandora and all that other stuff- which leaves me lost on this.

Anyone have any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the DNS settings of the various devices (because your IMAC does not seem to be affected).

Comment: Once the OP's eyeballs are affixed on the settings, what are the rest of the steps to solve the problem?  Without that, this seems like the kind of hint that might be more appropriate as a comment.  Just sayin.